# .rdata object load and use the variable through R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to load the .rdata object through user input , if the object is found then get the length of the list that is stored in the object else length is 1.
I am using the below code:

```
output$M_name<-renderUI({
if(file.exists(obj_name())==TRUE) 
{
  modname<<-load(file=objname,envir=sys.frame()) 
  ver<<-  length(get(modname))+1
  str1 <- paste0("-   ",isolate(input$model_name)," already EXISTS.")
  str2 <- paste("-    Please upload the new data csv file of the above mentioned model")
  HTML(paste(str1, str2, sep = "<br/>"))
}else
{
  modname<<-isolate({input$model_name})
  ver<<-length(get(modname))+1

  str1<-paste0("-   ",isolate(input$model_name)," does not EXIST")
  str2<-paste("-    Please use the same name, if you have already uploaded base model details before")
  str3<-paste("-    If this is the first time, Please upload the csv file on the next page")
  HTML(paste(str1, str2, str3, sep = "<br/>"))
}

  })
```

The file gets loaded and the object is saved in "modname" but i do not see the "ver" variable in the r environment.

I am fairly new to R shiny, please bear with my coding.